# Как кратко записать способ перемешивания чисел в диапазоне?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, множества

Как определить перемешивание набора N элементов относительно небольшим числом параметров?

Для диапазона равного степеням двойки я использовал изменение порядка битов. Т.е. для сохранения перемешивания `2^i` элементов, мне достаточно было сохранить i чисел от 0 до i.

Сейчас понадобилось похожим коротким образом задать перемешивание диапазона `1 – N` (N порядка 1e7).

Comment: Вопрос, на самом деле, неясен. *Произвольную* перестановку? Никак, разумеется. Или нужно семейство перестановок, обладающих свойством выглядеть случайно?  Тогда следует уточнить, для какого приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего взять массив с элементами от 1 до N и [случайно его перемешать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/110570/1988244).

на C#

```
static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this Random rng, T[] array)
    {
        int n = array.Length;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            int k = rng.Next(n--);
            T temp = array[n];
            array[n] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}

//.. 
var rand = new Random();
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).ToArray();

rand.Shuffle(array);
```

и дальше доставать из него по по индексу i-1 для i-го числа.

10^7 чисел у меня на машине перемешивает за 800ms, сложность линейная.

Comment: Да, решение рабочее, я встречал его рекомендации для подобных задач. Мне **любопытно**, есть ли подходящая математика для именно *красивого* решения: ф-ии и малого числа коэффициентов, задающих мутацию. О шифровании и криптоустойчивости речи не идёт. Как для перестановки битов достаточно, скажем, всего 32 чисел от 0 до 31, и это позволяет однозначно перемешать 4 млрд. значений. Вот бы найти похожее решение для произвольной длины блока.

Comment: @Sergiks это и есть функция для малого числа коэффициентов - ее результат полностью зависит от seed рандома - т.е. от int32. Достаточно написать `new Random(seed)` - и для одного и того же seed она выдаст один и тот же результат.Для произвольной длины блока можно просто повторить операцию 32 раза, используя значение из предыдущей операции как индекс в следующей. Результат будет функцией от 32 сидов. Вот только работать будет не слишком быстро.

Comment: @Sergiks ну или можно использовать для перемешивания не один рандом, а пул, 32 штуки для 32 разных seed. И добавить ротацию - генерировать по 1000 случаныйх чисел из каждого. Тогда результат будет функцией от 32 сидов, но работать будет чуть быстрее.

Comment: Так ведь могут быть коллизии – для двух разных входных чисел, одно и то же на выходе.  А, нет - понял вашу идею!

Comment: Нужно лишь использовать ГПСЧ, который одинаково будет срабатывать на разных машинах и зависеть только от `seed`.

Answer (score 1):

На ум приходят три метода:

1. `y = f(i) % N` при нелинейной функции `f`;
2. `y = rand<sup>i</sup>() % N`, то есть для `i`-того числа `i` раз вызываем функцию `rand` с заранее установленным фиксированным `seed`-ом.
3. `y = crc32(i) % N` где вместо crc32 можно использовать любую битомешалку.

Наиболее перспективно выглядит 3-ий вариант, либо комбинация из 1 и 2. Пример:

```
int rnd(int i, int N)
{
    int iSalt = i % 10;
    int seed = Math.Floor(183 * Math.Exp(iSalt + 135973));
    int random = new Random(seed);

    int iRemainer = i / 10;
    while (iRemainder > 0)
    {
        random.Next(N);
        iRemainer--;
    }

    return random.Next(N);
}
```

Comment: random может выдавать одинаковые результаты (чаще, чем раз в int32 раз). `crc32(i) / N` тоже может выдать один и тот же результат для разных i. а по условию результат должен быть разным для разных i.

Comment: Конкретно этот рандом не выдаёт одинаковых результатов чаще, чем в int32 раз. Но если не верите системному рандому, берите линейный конгруэнтный метод с [подходящими коэффициентами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4). Он как раз даёт неповторяющиеся числа с заданным периодом.

Comment: я вполне верю системному рандому, но я не могу понять как именно он у вас используется в коде. цикл `while (iRemainder > 0)` выглядит бесконечным, что немного сбивает с толку.

Comment: Понял. Это потому, что я вбивал код прямо на сайте, и ошибся. Конечно, на каждой итерации `iRamainer` должен уменьшаться на 1. Внёс изменения в код. Вообще, обратите внимание как раз на использование конгруэнтного метода, потому что он позволяет генерировать неповторяющуюся последовательность любого наперёд заданного периода. Одна беда: при непосредственном использовании для i-го члена надо вызывать функцию i раз, что довольно неэффективно.

Comment: Попробуйте написать реально работающий код. В текущем варианте `Math.Exp(iSalt + 135973)` выдает Infinity, и seed не зависит от i. И функция выдает одно и то же значение для i от 0 до 9. Если заменить его на другой сид, привязанный к iSalt - например на `seed = iSalt` начинает работать, но выдает дубликаты по другой причине - например, для (0, 1000) и (434, 1000) - потому что первый Next с seed = 0 оказывается равен 44-ому Next для seed=4.

Comment: линейный конгруэнтный метод - ок. но явный пример вычесления коэффициентов стоило бы привети в ответе, а не комментариях.